# How can I estimate the minimum baudrate for a given bitrate?

Tags: serial, uart, bluetooth, baudrate, data-acquisition

My circuit performs data acquisition at 250 samples/s, 24 bits/sample and transmit this information to the local host (PC) through a bluetooth module that implements the UART protocol.

As far as I know, for each byte transmitted there is 1 start bit, 2 stop bits and 1 parity bit, resulting

(250 samples/s) * (24 bits/sample) / (8 bits/byte) * (12 bits/transmitted byte) = 9000 bits

in 1 second.

Supposing there is one bit per transmitted symbol, the minimum  baudrate that would work for this case is 9600 bauds. However, the tests we've performed so far are not convincing, since the received data is contaminated by some enormous jump discontinuities (about 10^13, see figure below).

1. Could you please tell me how I can estimate the minimum baudrate?
2. How would you estimate the baudrate when including the bluetooth module?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "enormous jump discontinuities"?  Is this something you're seeing on an oscilloscope?  Or something else?

Comment: The bluetooth module doesn't say in its datasheet? It should.

Comment: Baud rate is not the primary concern here.  You need to think about the throughput of the bluetooth link (especially if it needs retries to deal with radio conditions).  Your jumps are probably those between bluetooth packets.  It's not entirely clear bluetooth is appropriate for your application or which variation of it you are using.

Comment: @scorpdaddy, see attached figure.

Comment: @Toor , I have not seen that information in the BT module datasheet. Anyway, I'll take a look at it again.

Comment: @ChrisStratton , I agree with you. On one hand, I need to know the baudrate for a given data bitrate. On the other hand, I need to know how much the baudrate should be increased when including the bluetooth module.
Thank you all for your helpful comments!

Comment: what you're calling "enormous jump discontinuities" look like some kind of measurement error to me.

Comment: @fmarengo - no you are still not understanding.  The bluetooth won't require you to *increase* the baud rate, rather for a reasonable baud rate the bluetooth rather than the baud rate will probably be the limitation.

Comment: What exactly is that a plot of?  What is 14x10^15 to start with?  It falls to 10X10^15 after 5000 of what?  What are the x and y axes?  This is obviously not an oscilloscope trace.  What is it?

Comment: It certainly seems as if your problem has absolutely nothing to do with baud rate.  It seems to be something to do with the bluetooth module you refuse to talk about.  And why did you delete the schematic?  If you want people to help you then stop being coy and start providing a lot more information.

Comment: @scorpdaddy the plot is a time series of a data acquisition system that measures 250 samples/s at 24 bits/sample. I have the results, but not the schematics (my colleague has it). According to the analysis I made, the acquired signal contains two envelopes, and the upper envelope is equal to the lower envelope. The only difference between them is the above mentioned jump discontinuity of 10^13.

**What do you suggest to do here?** Read the raw signal **before** the BT module? In this case, which baudrate do you recommend? 
Thanks!

Comment: Regardless of the problem reported here, **how I can estimate the minimum baudrate for a given bitrate?** 
If you don't know the answer, where can I find information about it?
Thank you all.

Comment: In terms of the minimum transmit baud rate - your calculation above is adequate.  I might multiply the 9000 by 1.1 = 9900 to allow for breaks between messages - not because its needed on the transmit side, but because it is frequently needed on the receive side.  Now the real problem, there is no way to determine the minimum baud rate on the receive side because you continue to refuse to disclose the device on the receive side.  There is probably a spec in the datasheet for the receive device that calls for a minimum of time between messages.